# Resuming Android app from an ongoing notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am working with notifications for the first time, and it seems that i must be missing something obvious. I have an Android app that plays music. While it is playing, I have an ongoing notification displayed so I can easily get back to my app if it is in the background. My problem is that when I click the notification, it opens a whole new instance of the application, instead of resuming the previous instance.

I have a PendingIntent set up to launch my app, and a call to PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,myIntent, 0) 
I've tried different settings for the last parameter, but same results. What am I missing?

Mark D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit your Activity's entry in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to include `android:launchMode` (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for the options). Most likely will be anything but `standard`. Also see if playing around with [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#reparent) and or [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always) may help.

Comment: Thank you! Setting android:launchMode = "singleTop" took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use (in my countdown app):

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```